# Help with php mysql query adding 3rd table

Tags: php

I need help w/a php query, and will start by explaining the obvious that I'm over my head with this.

The query, which works (pretty much*), randomly selects from 2 tables products with certain criteria.    My  issue is I need not just the field products.vendorid, but the actual vendor *name* which is located in another table, table: vendor.  So products.vid is the vendor of the product - and I need to go into the vendor table and lookup the fields vendor.company that matches.

I don't know how to introduce this 3rd table in here that's mainly a lookup. I'm trying to keep in within the same recordset and wondering if a subquery is of use here or something else?
The query:

```
SELECT products.pid, products.vendorid, products.is_visible, 
       product_description.compare1, product_description.title
FROM products, product_description 
WHERE products.pid >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(pid) * RAND()) FROM `products` ) 
  and ((product_description.compare1 = 'Cohasset' ) 
  and (products.is_visible='Yes') and (products.pid = product_description.pid))
LIMIT 5
```

To clarify - I need  a field called 'vendor.company', in the table 'vendor', which contains vendor id, called 'vid' which matches up with products.vendorid.

Hope this makes sense and I appreciate the help.

*(not 100%: if the random number generated is more than 5 less than the total products but I can live w/that for now)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT products.pid, products.vendorid, products.is_visible, 
       product_description.compare1, product_description.title,
       vendor.company
FROM products, product_description, vendor
WHERE products.pid >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(pid) * RAND()) FROM `products` ) 
  and ((product_description.compare1 = 'Cohasset' ) 
  and (products.is_visible='Yes') and (products.pid = product_description.pid))
  and vendor.vid = products.vendorid
LIMIT 5
```

To break this down:

> I need a field called 'vendor.company',

So we add `vendor.company` To the end of the `SELECT` section at the top.

> in the table 'vendor',

So we add `vendor` to the `FROM` list

> contains vendor id, called 'vid' which matches up with products.vendorid.

So we add `vendor.vid = products.vendorid` to the `WHERE`

Comment: +1 correct and good explanation. I would only change `WHERE` conditions to `JOIN`s for joining the tables.

Comment: I've always favored JOIN myself as well, but I have to be honest: I'm not sure what the practical difference is (anyone who knows, please chime in!).  I assume mysql optimizes to a JOIN of some sort, but hell if I know what kind of JOIN...  In this case, I opted to keep the query structure as much as possible in hopes of keeping things simple for the OP to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `JOIN` instead of `WHERE`, where possible:

```
SELECT products.pid
     , products.vendorid
     , products.is_visible
     , product_description.compare1
     , product_description.title
     , vendor.company
FROM products
  JOIN product_description
    ON products.pid = product_description.pid
  JOIN vendor
    ON vendor.vid = products.vendorid
WHERE products.pid >=
        ( SELECT FLOOR( MAX(pid) * RAND())
          FROM products ) 
  and (product_description.compare1 = 'Cohasset') 
  and (products.is_visible = 'Yes') 
LIMIT 5
```